# Extracting Files between two dates which has been saved with dates

Tags: python, pandas, file

I have saved all the daily sales reports in a common folder. each file is named with the corresponding date. eg: 01-01-2019-Sales.csv, 02-01-2019-Sales.csv, etc. all the files are saved in the "C:\Desktop\Sales" folder path. now i want to extract &  combine all the files which are between 05-01-2019 to 04-02-2019.

I know I can extract all the files with pandas using the below code

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

file_path = r'C:\Desktop\Sales'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,'*.csv'))
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files], sort=False)
```

But, my question is how can i extract files between 2 given specific dates using pandas/python. (using the file names which has been saved with the date) eg ; extract only the files between 05-01-2019 to 04-02-2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates could be compared lexically with a change to yyyy-mm-dd.

```
L = [ '01-01-2019-Sales.csv', '02-01-2019-Sales.csv']
>>> start = '2018-12-01'
>>> end = '2019-02-01'

>>> for file in L:
    m, d, yr = file.split('-')[:3]
    date = '-'.join([yr, m, d])
    if start <= date <= end:
        print(file)


01-01-2019-Sales.csv
02-01-2019-Sales.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this

```
start_date = "05-01-2019"
end_date = "04-02-2019"

all_csv_files = [x for x in os.listdir(file_path) if x.endswith('.csv')]
correct_date_files = [x for x in all_csv_files 
                      if x >= start_date + "-Sales.csv" and x <= end_date + "-Sales.csv"]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in correct_date_files], sort=False)
```

You basically just list all `.csv` files in your directory and only take the ones between the chosen dates.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this piece of code will help you

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.date(2019,1,1)
d2 = datetime.date(2019,2,1)

d3 = datetime.date(2019,1,20)
d4 = datetime.date(2019,2,20)

print(d1<d3<d2)
# True
print(d1<d4<d2)
# False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dates as comparison:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
from time import strptime

file_path = r'C:\Desktop\Sales'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,'*.csv'))
start_date = strptime('04-02-2019', '%m-%d-%Y')
end_date = strptime('05-01-2019', '%m-%d-%Y')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files
                if start_date < strptime(f, '%d-%m-%Y.csv') < end_date],
               sort=False)
```